# getting an error trying to register device with Azure Notification Hub

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-notificationhub

I have a xamarin app That will send notifications via Azure functions and its notification hub out put binding.

In xamarin app i have an android service that gets the token and stores in cache

```
    [Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
public class MyFirebaseIIDService : FirebaseInstanceIdService
{
    private App _app => (App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current;
    private readonly ICachingService _cachingService;
    public MyFirebaseIIDService()
    {
        var xx = typeof(ICachingService);
        _cachingService = (CachingService)App.Instance.Container.Resolve(xx);

    }
    public override void OnTokenRefresh()
    {

            var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
            _cachingService.FireBaseToken = refreshedToken;
            Console.WriteLine($"Token received: {refreshedToken}");
       //     SendRegistrationToServerAsync(refreshedToken);

    }

}
```

after the user is logged in i want to use its Id as tag and i call another android service that tries to register a device with this tag

```
  var client = new MobileServiceClient(App.MobileServiceUrl);
            var push = client.GetPush();
            var reg = new Registration(token, tags);
            await push.RegisterAsync(reg);
```

at this point i have token and tags list that contains userId because later i want that this user only gets notification meant for them only.

on the push.RegisterAsyn method i get an error.

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

please note that the App.MobileServiceUrl is the url of Azure Mobile App that is connected to notification hub

[image]

Other than that this Azure Mobile App have just the default TODO controllers and everything that comes with the template. My sending notification code will be in azure functions using notification hub output binding.

I also updated all azure related nugets no diffrence
 it tries to hit this url for registration. 
    https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/push/registrations?deviceId=dTd4wba1KTU:APA91bHKOZRX9LFzEGD-yqyz4p-whqh6UsoEAlgpFHfBxu00MhLo-------yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyeuoRmH4h9czeQbvGRgbwt4zMlrvRIlvLDZ-kTu_Dcu2iHx9I5u0gheQQ3Z2tYq66O&platform=gcm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was using a wrong nuget. i had to use

Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client

instead i was using Azure Mobile Services nuget.

both have MobileServiceClient class thats why i got confused. now i dont get the exception.